# FlatButton child is not centered inside the button

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget that displays a Text with and a FlatButton with an Icon.
The problem is that the icon is not centered inside the button.
[image]

Here's the code I'm using:

```
child: Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text("Text", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
    Container(
      color: Colors.lightBlue,
      width: 40.0,
      child: FlatButton(onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.edit, size: 20.0, color: Colors.white,),
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a default padding on `FlatButton` set it to `EdgeInsets.zero`
Like this

```
FlatButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      onPressed: (){},
      child: Icon(Icons.edit)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

hello you should use another type of buttons, for example:

```
        IconButton(
          color: Colors.lightBlue,
          icon: Icon(Icons.edit, size: 20.0, color: Colors.white,),
          onPressed: () { },
        ),
```

for more buttons you can see the official website :
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/material#Buttons